# добавить свойство каждому object в array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

прошу помочь с добавлением свойств в каждый из объектов массива. Вот пример array на фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таких object у меня 20 - мне нужно в каждый из них добавить свойство `result: ' '`

Вот кусок кода, в котором нужно это вставить :

```
for(let wl = 0; wl < $scope.matches.length; wl++){
        $scope.matches[wl]
        if($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == true && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot <= 127){
            $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'Win Match';
        } else if ($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == false && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot <= 127) {
            $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'Lost Match';
        } else if ($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == true && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot >= 128) {
            $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'Lost Match';
        } else if ($scope.matches[wl].radiant_win == false && $scope.matches[wl].player_slot >= 128) {
            $scope.matches[wl].radiant_win = 'Win Match';
        }
    };
```

Здесь 2 строчка (`$scope.matches[wl]`) - это и есть каждый объект массива.

Comment: [How to add property to each object of an array in typescript.?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48953461/how-to-add-property-to-each-object-of-an-array-in-typescript)

Comment: @nilecrocodile Спасибо - все помогло!

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.matches[wl] = Object.assign($scope.matches[wl], {
                result: '' 
            })
```

Спасибо @nilecrocodile за подсказку!